# Anchor smooth scrolling not working on a Wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, scrolltop

I have this smooth anchor scroll code inserted on my Wordpress site http://www.ilovestvincent.com

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {

        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = jQuery(target);

        jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $(target).offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

This should trigger a smooth scroll when clicking the top menu links but it's not working. This code is working fine on my other sites but I'm stumped as to why it wouldn't be working on ilovestvincent.com.

Any tips would be highly appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Try to change target to var target = $(this).attr('href')

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet which should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {

       var target = jQuery(this).attr('href');

       jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
         'scrollTop': target.offset().top
       }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
       });

   });
});
```